# css3 :contains selector not work

Tags: css

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong, but `:contains` css selector not work for me. Is it excluded from current css3 implementation? I check it in FF, chrome and IE, all of them ignore `background: red` property.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.a {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 20px;
height: 30px;
position: relative;
}

.a:contains("1") {
background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="a">1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: CSS doesn't have a `:contains` selector, javascript and jQuery has a method though

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors and here http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/18/css3-selectors.html?page=2

Comment: Documents from 2001 are not valid anymore. There is talk of a `:has()` selector, but it's not clear if that will ever be implemented, and it would work only for subselectors, not text content.

Comment: @Mr Lister: I've stated numerous times that the CSSWG really needs to slap on the same gigantic "This document is obsolete" notices that the HTML WG does with theirs.

Comment: @LGSon: [heh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955530/how-to-ignore-matches-in-descendent-elements-when-using-jquery-contains)

Comment: @BoltClock Just added a link in my answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pseudo-class `:contains()` has been removed from the specs.

> 6.6.6. Blank
>
> This section intentionally left blank. (This section previously
>   defined a `:contains()` pseudo-class.)

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors

---

Here is how you can use javascript, or jQuery (12th answer)

- [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks man, I need no references about js. I bet with one guy, that I will do html+css calculator.

Comment: @degr You might still can...though _that_ is a new question :)

Comment: A calculator written in CSS? That would be a challenge. I wouldn't get much further than [this](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/rLta157b/).

Comment: @MrLister Nice try :) ... was actually not thinking that far when I said _might still can_, though now you made the _think_ :) and I can't see how that would be possible