# How to ignore matches in descendent elements when using jQuery :contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I looked at [jQuery selector for an element that directly contains text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896455/jquery-selector-for-an-element-that-directly-contains-text), but the suggested solutions were all quite involved.

I tried to select the second `div`, which contains some text as below.

```
<div>
    <div>
        mytext
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery command:

```
$('div:contains("mytext")').css("color", "red)
```

Unfortunately this also selects (makes red) all the parent `divs` of the `div` that I would like to select. This is because `:contains` looks for a match within the selected element and also its descendants.

Is there an analogous command, which will not look for a match in the descendants? I would not like to select all the parent `divs`, just the `div` that contains the text directly.

Comment: That's because all the ancestor `div`s match the selector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery selector for an element that directly contains text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896455/jquery-selector-for-an-element-that-directly-contains-text)

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Why are you repeating a statement from the question in a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the probem is that `$('div:contains("mytext")')` will match all `divs` that contains `myText` text or that their child nodes contains it.

You can either identify those divs with `id` or a `class` so your selector will be specific for this case:

```
$('div.special:contains("mytext")').css("color", "red");
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('div.special:contains("mytext")').css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="special">
        mytext
    </div>
</div>
```

Or, in your specific case, use a resitriction in your selector to avoid the divs that has child nodes with `:not(:has(>div))`:

```
$('div:not(:has(>div)):contains("mytext")').css("color", "red");
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('div:not(:has(>div)):contains("mytext")').css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        mytext
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is better that `last()` imo, on which i wouldn't rely for this

Comment: Could someone elaborate on what's the issue with using `last()`? It worked in my case.

Comment: @Andras With `.last()` you are matching the collection of nodes, then you are calling another jQuery method `.last()` to reduce this collection into the last one, while with `:not`selctor you are doing it all in one operation. Another thing `.last()` won't be always relevant in the case where you have more than one sub divs elements that contains `myText`, it will just match the last one, please refer to [**this example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/n15nq2w4/).

Comment: @Kaddah yes indeed, `.last()` won't be always relevant, like in [**this case**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/n15nq2w4/).

Comment: In the actual setup the `div` I'd like to select has another `div` in it...

Comment: @Andras Then just use a `class` to identify this specific div.

Comment: OK, thanks! `last()` actually works OK in my case. The guy even deleted his answer after the downvotes. That one worked for me.

Comment: @Andras You are welcome, I am not the downvoter, but as I said, `.last()` can be useful in your speciifc case but not in all cases, when we post solutions here we should always remember that ther will be future readers of the post, that doesn't have the same exact case. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the target `div` with `find()` method in jQuery.

**Example:**

```js
$('div').find(':contains("mytext")').css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        mytext
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Following example with `filter()` in jQuery.

```js
$('div').filter(function(i) {
  return this.innerHTML.trim() == "mytext";
}).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  test2
  <div>
    test
    <div>
      mytext
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can anyone tell what can be the reason for down vote?

Comment: `find()` seems to be doing the same thing as plain `:contains("mytext")`. It also returns all the parents.

Comment: @Andras It will not select the parent elements. You can check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ez3zy75z/

Comment: It doesn't completely work as intended https://jsfiddle.net/ez3zy75z/3/

Comment: looks good! I've already upvoted your answer, so can't upvote anymore. I would otherwise.